# Standard Android styleAttribute layout_width not being resolved but layout_height is

Tags: android, attributes

Ive been developing a custom android view. It is nested within a Relative layout with a couple of other views. The issue im having is that when im retrieving the attribute values programatically im able to get the `android.R.Attr.layout_height` but for some unknown bizarre reason `android.R.Attr.layout_width` will not resolve the value and defaults to the specified default value.

This is being developed within android studio and using android 4.4.

Activity xml (omitting other elements):

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialFrame"
        android:layout_width="440px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="60px"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dialModifierGroup"
        android:clipChildren="false">

        <com.test.Views.CustomView
            android:id="@+id/dialElement"
            android:layout_height="440px"
            android:layout_width="440px"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
     </RelativeLayout>
```

Underlying Class constructor:

```
    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    super(context, attrs);

    int[] attrsArray = new int[] {
            android.R.attr.layout_height,
            android.R.attr.layout_width,
            android.R.attr.x,
            android.R.attr.y,
    };

    TypedArray ta = parentCtx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attrsArray);

    height = ta.getDimensionPixelSize(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    width = ta.getDimensionPixelSize(1, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    xpos = ta.getDimensionPixelSize(2, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) + (width/2);
    ypos = ta.getDimensionPixelSize(3, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)+ (height/2);


    ta.recycle();

}
```

Is there any special reason why `layout_width` will not resolve in a Relative layout?

I cant see any physical reason why this should not give back the correct values.

Please say if you need other files from the project but note i have not touched anything else im aware of.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please ignore the px values - this app is in its infancy.